# Initialize WOW.js inside Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to find the right place to initialize wow.js within an angular.js app. I tried putting it before (outside) of controller code, but it doesn't work.

Putting the init code inside of a view's controller like below works, but causes the UI to flicker as the init must be getting fired multiple times when a view loads.

```
csvApp.controller('ResumeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    new WOW().init();
});
```

Where should 'new WOW().init();' go?

( link to wow.js http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/ )

Answer (score 5):

Easy way: you could initialize it in the `.config` phase of your app.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [ /* dependencies */])
    .config(function() {
        new WOW().init();
    })
```

More elaborate way: build a `provider` around the library and inject it in the `config` function.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment i use the $rootScope and $routeChangeStart, you could use $routeChangeSuccess i suppose.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

       //create a new instance
       new WOW().init();

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (next, current) {
        //when the view changes sync wow
        new WOW().sync();
    });
}]);
```

Comment: I'm using this one in an angular-meteor project

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize it outside the controller.
In your code I'm guessing it'll be something like:

```
<script>
new WOW().init();

csvApp.controller('ResumeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    /* your angularjs code */
});
</script>
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cFsX/1/) to see it in action (scroll down for wow.js effect).

Comment: @Chava.Sobreyra, well... consider posting a fiddle. Anyways, check *my* fiddle, it shows my solution should work in the general case

Answer (score 0):

For me, the working solution was initialize it inside the controller, but after the entire DOM is loaded, in order to fire the animations when scrolling and not when the page loads:

```
angular.module('AA')
       .controller('Controller', function() {
            angular.element(document).ready(function() {
               new WOW().init();
            });
       });
```